# Filtering, grouping and comparing challenge

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am very new to sql, and programming in general. I thankfully accept all help I can get.

This is the challenge:
**Pick one city and category of your choice and group the businesses in that city or category by their overall star rating. Compare the businesses with 2-3 stars to the businesses with 4-5 stars and answer the following questions.**

This is my code so far, but I am not getting any results nor the right results:

```
SELECT b.city, c.category, b.stars as Rating
FROM business b inner join category c on b.id = c.business_id
WHERE b.city = 'Mesa' and c.category = 'salad'
GROUP BY Rating
```

Attached is the Yelp ERD which this is based upon.[YELP ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL5LF.png)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide your sample data and expected result?

Comment: There's a link in [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) to a tool that makes it very easy to create ascii tables.

Answer (score 0):

Pick one city and category of your choice and group the businesses in that city or category by their overall star rating.

The following example will count the number of businesses in a specified city and category and groups it by rating.

```
SELECT Count(*) as Total_Businesses, b.stars as Rating
FROM business b join category c on b.id = c.business_id
WHERE b.city = 'Mesa' and c.category = 'salad'
GROUP BY b.stars
```

Compare the businesses with 2-3 stars to the businesses with 4-5 stars.
This wil compare the difference in reviews between the different types of businesses.

```
SELECT Count(*) as total_reviews, 
       b.stars as Stars,
       sum(r.stars)/Count(*) as avg_review_score
FROM business b 
  JOIN category c on b.id = c.business_id
  JOIN review r on r.business_id = b.id
WHERE b.city = 'Mesa' and c.category = 'salad'
GROUP BY b.stars
Having b.stars > 1
```